# Valid CSS not being applied in HTML in a React Native WebView

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, android-webview

I have a valid page made with html and css which, when run on the browser, the output is as expected. I am trying to render that html page in a `WebView`, but  the CSS styling isn't being applied and I can't understand why. This is how I'm doing it:

```
public render() {
    const css = `<style> /* ...all css styling goes here */ </style>`;
    const html = `<body> /* ...all html goes here */ </body>`;
    return (
        <WebView
            originWhitelist={["*"]}
            source={{html: css + html}}
        />
    );
}
```

What am I missing here? As I said, the css and html part is exactly as it is in the page, and when I open the page in the browser it works perfectly fine.